# Customize Straight Line Graph on Grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Despite the many questions and answers on SE, I am unable to customize the following graph I am trying to plot.

[image: Original Image I am trying to plot using pgfplot]

My current effort is:

[image: Basic LaTeX code I have written till now]

The code for above image is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both,
            grid style={line width=.5pt, draw=black!30},
            major grid style={line width=.5pt,draw=black!30}, 
            clip=false,
            xmin=0,xmax=65,
            ymin=0,ymax=55,
            enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
            xtick={0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60},
            ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50},
            xticklabels={\empty},
            yticklabels={,,},
            extra x ticks={0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60},
            extra x tick labels={,,,,,$25$,$30$,$35$,$40$,$45$,$50$,$55$,$60$},
            extra y ticks={{0,10,20,30,40,50}},
            extra y tick labels={,$10$,$20$,$30$,$40$,$50$},
            minor x tick num=1,
            minor y tick num=1,
            axis lines=left,
            axis x discontinuity=crunch
]
\addplot[latex-latex, samples=2,domain=23:58] coordinates {(23,19) (25,20) (50,35) (58.5,40) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Customization required:

- Straight Line crossing y-axis at around 14.
- Dotted Line from <25 beyond negative x-axis.
- Reduce gap between 0 and 25 value of x-axis.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the third point, all you need to do is to modify `xmin`.

Looking at your image, aren't the first two points the same question? Anyways, one option could be to calculate the equation of the straight line running through the first and last of your coordinates, and use that to plot a dashed line from e.g. x=10 to x=23.

Note I simplified your tick settings quite a lot, and changed the `axis lines` setting to `middle`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   grid=both,
   grid style={line width=.5pt, draw=black!30},
   major grid style={line width=.5pt,draw=black!30}, 
   clip=false,
   xmin=20, % modified
   xmax=64,
   ymin=0,ymax=54,
   xtick distance=5,  % added
   ytick distance=10,  % added
   minor x tick num=1,
   minor y tick num=1,
   axis lines=middle, % changed to middle
   axis x discontinuity=crunch
]
%\addplot[latex-latex] coordinates {(23,19) (25,20) (50,35) (58.5,40) };

% equation of line calculated based on (23,19) and (58.5,40) 
\addplot[latex-latex, samples at={23,58.5}] {0.59155*x + 5.394366};
\addplot[densely dashed, samples at={10,23}] {0.59155*x + 5.394366};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}​
```